C# code responding differently to serial port than putty
I'm struggling with this one since last 2 days. Would really appetite any pointers.
Summery: I am connecting to a system over serial. I can make it do anything I want with putty. For any command I send it, It returns back the command followed by <00> for success and <21> for error. The command to clear the error is 'KL' so if in putty I send KL and get KL<21> back, if I send KL again I get KL<00> back every time without fail. Challenge is, when I send the same sequence of commands from my C# code, I always get KL<21> back. Even if I connect in putty, send KL, get KL<21>, send KL again to get KL<00> in response(so that the error clears out before opening the C# code). If I disconnect putty and then connect using C#, I get the first response as KL<00> and every other command(including KL) as <21>.
putty config :

Putty Response:

C# UI :

C# code: [Ignore the scale and Vacc as they are working fine so far]
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection.Emit;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace PortApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!serialPort1.IsOpen)
            {
                serialPort1.PortName = com.Text;
                serialPort1.BaudRate = int.Parse(baud.Text);
                serialPort1.DataBits = int.Parse(databit.Text);
                // Parity
                if (parity.Text.ToLower() == "n")
                {
                    serialPort1.Parity = System.IO.Ports.Parity.None;
                }
                else if (parity.Text.ToLower() == "o")
                {
                    serialPort1.Parity = System.IO.Ports.Parity.Odd;
                }
                else if (parity.Text.ToLower() == "e")
                {
                    serialPort1.Parity = System.IO.Ports.Parity.Even;
                }
                else if (parity.Text.ToLower() == "m")
                {
                    serialPort1.Parity = System.IO.Ports.Parity.Mark;
                }
                else if (parity.Text.ToLower() == "s")
                {
                    serialPort1.Parity = System.IO.Ports.Parity.Space;
                }
                // StopBits
                if (stopbit.Text.ToLower() == "n")
                {
                    serialPort1.StopBits = System.IO.Ports.StopBits.None;
                }
                else if (stopbit.Text.ToLower() == "1")
                {
                    serialPort1.StopBits = System.IO.Ports.StopBits.One;
                }
                else if (stopbit.Text.ToLower() == "1.5")
                {
                    serialPort1.StopBits = System.IO.Ports.StopBits.OnePointFive;
                }
                else if (stopbit.Text.ToLower() == "2")
                {
                    serialPort1.StopBits = System.IO.Ports.StopBits.Two;
                }
                // FlowControl
                if (flowcontrol.Text.ToLower() == "n")
                {
                    serialPort1.Handshake = Handshake.None;
                    serialPort1.RtsEnable = true;
                    serialPort1.DtrEnable = true;
                }
                else if (flowcontrol.Text.ToLower() == "h")
                {
                    serialPort1.Handshake = Handshake.RequestToSend;
                }
                else if (flowcontrol.Text.ToLower() == "xonxoff")
                {
                    serialPort1.Handshake = Handshake.XOnXOff;
                }
                else if (flowcontrol.Text.ToLower() == "hxonxoff")
                {
                    serialPort1.Handshake = Handshake.RequestToSendXOnXOff;
                }


                // connect
                // Set the read/write timeouts
                serialPort1.ReadTimeout = 500;
                serialPort1.WriteTimeout = 1000;

                try
                {
                    serialPort1.Open();
                    textBox2.Text += "\r\n==================";
                    textBox2.Text += "\r\nPort Opened";
                }
                catch
                {
                    Debug.Print(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss: ") + "Com port failed to open.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                textBox2.Text += "\r\n==================";
                textBox2.Text += "\r\nPort already Open";
            }

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!serialPort1.IsOpen)
            {
                textBox2.Text += "\r\n==================";
                textBox2.Text += "\r\nPort not Open";
            }
            else
            {
                serialPort1.Write(this.textBox1.Text+"\r\n");

                var data = "";
                var counter = 20;
                while (data == "" && counter > 0)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        counter -= 1;
                        data = serialPort1.ReadLine();
                        Console.Write(".'"+data+"'\n");
                        //Thread.Sleep(1000);
                        textBox2.Text += "\r\n" + textBox1.Text;
                        textBox2.Text += "\r\n: '" + data+"'";
                        textBox1.Text = "";
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex) {
                        Debug.Print(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss: ") + "Exception1:::: "+ ex.Message);
                        Console.Write(">X>'" + ex.Message + "'\n");
                    }
                }

                try
                {
                    data = serialPort1.ReadLine();
                    Console.Write(">'" + data + "'\n");
                    textBox2.Text += "\r\n:: '" + data + "'";
                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Debug.Print(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss: ") + "Exception2:::: " + ex.Message);
                    Console.Write(">XX>'" + ex.Message + "'\n");
                }
            }

            
        }

        private void disconnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!serialPort1.IsOpen)
            {
                textBox2.Text += "\r\n==================";
                textBox2.Text += "\r\nPort not Open";
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write("Port Closed\n");
                textBox2.Text += "\r\nPort Closed";
                serialPort1.DiscardInBuffer();
                serialPort1.DiscardOutBuffer();
                serialPort1.Dispose();
                serialPort1.Close();
            }
        }

        private void robot_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            com.Text = "COM3";
            baud.Text  = "9600";
            databit.Text = "8";
            parity.Text = "o";
            stopbit.Text = "1";
            flowcontrol.Text = "N";
        }

        private void scale_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            com.Text = "COM4";
            baud.Text = "9600";
            databit.Text = "7";
            parity.Text = "o";
            stopbit.Text = "1";
            flowcontrol.Text = "N";

        }

        private void vacc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            com.Text = "COM6";
            baud.Text = "9600";
            databit.Text = "8";
            parity.Text = "n";
            stopbit.Text = "1";
            flowcontrol.Text = "N";

        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
            {
                serialPort1.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}




So, as I had almost exhausted all my options, I took a coffee break out of frustration.
Upon return, I was trying to explore more on why the putty was working. I enables all the session logging and then opened the log like I have done 100's of time before in notepad++.
The one thing I did differently this time is, I enabled the Show all characters on notepad++.


and there, the answer to my struggle.. Because I was either passing \n(the line feed) along with my carriage return(\r) or I was using port.write"line"(), it always ended up sending a line feed at the end which resulted in error.
My other COM's are more forgiving on the \n / line feed so it never was a issue. I guess everyday is a learning huh.
